# Convert an array of objects to an array of values from the object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of country details:

`var countryArr = [{"name":"Afghanistan","alpha2Code":"AF"},{"name":"Åland Islands","alpha2Code":"AX"},{"name":"Albania","alpha2Code":"AL"},{"name":"Algeria","alpha2Code":"DZ"},{"name":"American Samoa","alpha2Code":"AS"},{"name":"Andorra","alpha2Code":"AD"},{"name":"Angola","alpha2Code":"AO"}]`

How can I get each value of the name attribute from this array?
So I end up with an array of country names:
["Afghanistan", "Åland Islands"...]

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve it on your own? This doesn't require more than a simple loop and an array for the names.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `Array.map`!

```
const justTheNames = countryArr.map(country => country.name);
```

**Explanation:** The `Array.map` method will iterate through the elements of the array, applying the given callback function to each and returning a new array with the return values from the callback. In this case, it'll iterate over the array of country objects and create a new array with just the country names.